# How to resolve error: short SHA1 <CommitHash> is ambiguous?

Tags: git, show

I used git show  and I get the following error,

```
error: short SHA1 94817b is ambiguous
hint: The candidates are:
hint:   94817b5aaa blob
hint:   94817b8c74 blob
fatal: ambiguous argument '94817b': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I'm trying to get the file in specific version of commit, I obtained the short commit hash from the diff object

Comment: Supply a longer abbreviated hash, or the full hash. There are two possible candidates here; presumably one of them is probably the file you want, and the other isn't.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that before hand just like you said one of them gives me the file I want and the other one gives me the something unrelated, as a human I can distinguish between those, but I'm running a script which does this work on multiple projects, to fetch files of different versions. Is there a way to choose the right Hash from the hints??

Comment: The good question is why you handle short sha1 in a script. Use the full hash and it will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell [git-diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff) to give you the *full SHA-1* of the blobs instead of the abbreviated version using the [--full-index](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---full-index) option:

> Instead of the first handful of characters, show the full pre- and post-image blob object names on the "index" line when generating patch format output.

For example:

```
git diff --full-index HEAD^..HEAD
```

will result in a diff header that looks like this:

```
diff --git a/path/to/file b/path/to/file
index 25c0cfd42393302780668d0f58c6c48333dc1f89..cf913856f0475d360ff45cc244568b53c56a5554 100644
```

instead of this:

```
diff --git a/path/to/file b/path/to/file
index 25c0cfd..cf91385 100644
```

Comment: That's a nice idea, but for it to work I have to checkout to previous commit versions, what I'm trying to achieve is to keep the repo in a fixed version (preferably latest version) and fetch the files of previous commit. I have got the a dataset which has the short commit hash, so that's why I'm using short hash.